# Inverse Function in terms of Surjective and Injective Functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is my intuition of the proof listed after
[image]

The mapping of A to A is an inverse function. The mapping of A to B is injective and the mapping from B to A is surjective.

[image]

I'm confused as to where the $s$ comes from in the proof and why it's there and I've seen other people proof on here but none have explained why the $s$ is there. Why is its chosen randomly? Aren't we supposed to throw the $s$ away?

Thanks,

Jackson

Comment: Note that, by definition, $g$ has to have the domain $B$, which means all of $B$.  How should we define $g(b)$ if there is no $a$ such that $b = f(a)$?  What's your intuition for how we would avoid choosing a "random" $s$?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a function that maps it like my diagram above and not be random?

Comment: as your diagram indicates, we have to send the $3$rd and $5$th elements of $B$ *somewhere*.  How do you decide what the "non-random" place to send those elements when $A$ and $B$ can be arbitrary sets?

Comment: It should be based on the function (if b is not the image of f then it should be from a different set but not random). Also shouldn't those not be included in the set since they are discarded later?

Comment: If we "didn't include" the extra elements, then we would no longer have a function $g:B\to A$.  We want the domain to be **all** of $B$.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use "random" in this context; random is a word with a precise mathematical meaning.  The preferred term for what you're trying to describe is an **arbitrary** element of $A$.

Comment: I see your point now and have a better understanding. But I still think it would be better to define it as b=f (c); c is not an image of f. My mistake arbitrary is a better choice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24892/discussion-between-omnomnomnom-and-jackson-h).

Comment: I recently came back to this and am wondering why is it that $s$ has to be fixed what if a function exists so that elements that are the image of $f$ are not fixed but the elements that are the image of $f$ still Mao back to the pre-image. Shouldn't $s$ be able to be any value in $A$? Also what if the images of $g$ that are not images of $f$ go outside of A but the ones that are the image of $f$ still go to $A $? It seems like this is assuming too much and isn't very specific.

Comment: First question: the point is that it doesn't matter what $g$ does to the elements outside of the image of $f$.  The easiest way to define a suitable $g$, however, is to say that we send all of those elements to some element $s$ of $A$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the images of $g$ that are not the images of $f$".  First of all, you presumably mean "elements of the image", not image.  Second, none of the elements of the image of $g$ are generally elements of the image of $f$ since the image of $g$ is a subset of $A$, and the image of $f$ is a subset of $B$.

Comment: I meant elements of the image of $g$ that were not fed in from $f$.

Comment: Shouldn't we follow what I said earlier where $s$ doesn't have to be fixed because there exists a function that is the inverse where $s$ isn't fixed.

Comment: The image of $g$ is a subset of $A$. $f$ feeds into $B$. None of the elements of the image of $g$ should be "fed in from $f$".

Comment: If you don't say where exactly $g$ sends the elements outside the image, then you haven't defined $g$ as a function from B to A. We didn't have to send everything outside the image to the same element $s$. However, we also don't need to describe every possible $g$ that works.

Comment: Sorry for my vocabulary but $f$ goes to a subset of $B $ and $g$ takes all of $B$ to $A$. There are ones that went to $A$ from $B$ but there are some $B$ which are not from $A$ but still go to $A$. Those are the ones I'm talking about. In my diagram above they are the 3rd and 5th blue elements that map to the 3rd and 5th green elements. Why wouldn't we have to? A proof has to work every time, not just once. My diagram above is a counter-example because the 3rd and 5th blue elements go to two different green elements

Comment: Let me know if I'm not being clear. It's hard to put some things in set theory into words without sounding complicated. We should probably switch to chat.

Comment: Now I understand what you're talking about.  Anyway, the question was to show that a left-inverse $g$ exists.  It is not necessary to describe every possible function $g$ that fulfills this role.

Comment: The book says that the $f $ has a right inverse if and only if it is surjective. Doesn't this mean it has to be true all the time  both ways (which would mean every possible case)?

Comment: It has to be true for every $f$.  In order to show this, it's enough to take an arbitrary $f$ and define **one** of the **many** $g$ that can work as a right inverse.

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much. I never thought that a couple sentence proof in this book could be so much more than meets the eye. If you write that on the answer section I'll give it a thumbs up.

Comment: You're welcome.  I think that what you've dealt with in this problem is going to keep coming up as you learn about mathematical proof.  Often, in order to prove a weaker statements, it helps to make decisions that can seem "random".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of the answering took place in the comments.  Here is a summary of what was said:

In order to prove that every injective $f$ has a left-inverse, it suffices to take an arbitrary such function $f$, construct **one** function $g$ that satisfies $g(f(x)) = x$ for all $x$ in $A$.  In particular, it is okay to make arbitrary decisions in constructing $g$ (such as the decision that each element outside the image of $f$ should be mapped to a fixed element $s \in A$) as long as:

- we have made no assumptions about $f$ other than the fact that which is given (i.e. that it is injective)
- we can show that $g$ acts as a left-inverse to this arbitrary $f$

In this context, there will be many possible inverses $g$ unless $f$ happens to also be surjective.  If $f$ fails to be surjective, then we have not constructed $g$ as a function from $B$ to $A$ until we have stated what $g$ does to elements outside the image of $f$.  Since this part of the definition (so long as we define $g$ somehow) doesn't affect *whether* $g$ acts as an inverse, we go with the simplest possible definition.  In particular, we find a single element of $A$, call it $s$, and map all the things we don't care about to that element.